# Checkbox Bubbling to div - Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a div that is surrounding a check-box. The Div has an event handler that checks the check-box, The check-box'es default behavior is to check or uncheck itself upon being clicked, however the event is bubbling down to the div and the divs function is canceling out the check-boxes function, How can i prevent the div's function from being fired when the check-box is clicked?

```
    <div id="CloseForMeEmailCBDIV" style="width:50px;margin-left:6px; margin-top:8px; height: 24px;">
<input id="CloseForMeEmailCB" onclick="" type="checkbox" style="margin-left:6px;margin-top:4.49px;  transform: scale(2);">  Email</input>
</div>
```

this is what i tried:

```
  document.getElementById('CloseForMeEmailCBDIV').addEventListener('click', function (evt) { 
document.getElementById('CloseForMeEmailCB').checked = 
!document.getElementById('CloseForMeEmailCB').checked; evt.preventDefault(); });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `evt.stopPropagation()` instead of `evt.preventDefault()`.

`preventDefault`, as the name implies, just blocks the default behavior, for example toggling a checkbox is the default action of clicking on a checkbox, which will be prevented (canceled).

[see example here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Examples#Example_5:_Event_Propagation)

That being said, **a)** events propagate up (from the "lowest" reachable element up) and **b)** in general you don't want to stop the propagation of events, because it stops the "natural way events behave" and can give you problems further down the road. **c)** cache your selected elements. there is no need to use `getElementById` twice in row. save the value once in a `var` and use that instead.

```
document.getElementById('CloseForMeEmailCBDIV').addEventListener('click', function (evt) { 
 var element = document.getElementById('CloseForMeEmailCB');
 element.checked = !element.checked; 
 evt.preventDefault(); 
});
```

Comment: When you say it might cause problems down the line, I merely want a specific area to check or uncheck the checkbox, I figure by stopping the propagation this will allow all clicks in a specific area to check or uncheck the checkbox, do you think that will create un-forseen issues?

Comment: the problem is that ALL clicks in this area will only be catched by that listener meaning it won't reach the parent div for example. in most cases it might cause no trouble, but there can be situations where you don't want to stop propagation. the rule of thumb is: don't stop propagation unless you really really have to (which is really rare)